# MySQL Stored Procedure With Two Input Datetime Values Not Returning Results

Tags: mysql, datetime

So I'm working through an example problem of using a two input values of a date range for a stored procedure in MySQL. I am able to create the procedure successfully, and the join can retrieve the data without an error, but when I actually try to use the stored procedure and put in a beginning date and end date, I get no data. Any idea why?

```
DELIMITER $$
USE northwind$$
CREATE PROCEDURE order_details_date(in begin_date DATETIME, in end_date DATETIME)
BEGIN 
SELECT 
    e.EmployeeID,
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.Region,
    o.OrderID,
    o.OrderDate,
    o.ShipRegion
FROM
    employees e
JOIN
    orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
WHERE o.OrderDate >= @begin_date AND
    o.OrderDate <= @end_date
ORDER BY o.OrderDate;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To be clear, I don't get an error, I just get a query result with no data. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `@` in front of a variable name, you are referring to a user defined session variable, **not** the input to your procedure. You need to remove the `@` symbols in front of those names i.e.

```
SELECT 
    e.EmployeeID,
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.Region,
    o.OrderID,
    o.OrderDate,
    o.ShipRegion
FROM
    employees e
JOIN
    orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
WHERE o.OrderDate >= begin_date AND
    o.OrderDate <= end_date
ORDER BY o.OrderDate;
```

Note you can use `BETWEEN` as shorthand e.g.

```
o.OrderDate BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date
```